# access Ubuntu remotely from android?

Tags: wireless, networking, android, remote-desktop

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 and using Android 4.1 Version based device.I'd like to access my Ubuntu from my Android device through remote access. I have already tried several apps from store and I am happy with them.

But I want to remote access through local network , not through Internet. what ever the clients I have already tried those are providing through Internet not from local network.

I have connected my mobile to my System Wi-Fi network.

Bottom-Line: How to access Ubuntu from Android through local network Wi-Fi Based ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a GUI, you can simply use SSH. The most well known Android SSH client is [Connectbot](https://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) and many Custom Android ROMs already come with an SSH client preinstalled.

In case you need a GUI, you can combine Connectbot with an X11 server for Android, but this works not very well at the moment of writing. Another option is to use a [VNC viewer](https://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/) for Android and to set up a VNC server on your Ubuntu machine.